# Adding partition to Lenovo Z580 without formating

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a Lenovo Z580 laptop which has already 4 partitions :

1. C: drive (NTFS)
2. System drive (NTFS)
3. Recovery
4. Lenovo (NTFS)

Making a new volume it not permitted, the error saying that dynamic disks are not supported.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa: Please stop changing the title. Adding a new partition to a 4-partition setup is one thing, trying to shrink a partition is another. They are two different questions!

Comment: Lenovos partition scheme is a bit crazy.. I got rid of the Recovery and Lenovo drives, they aren't very useful (to me).

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on the My Computer icon, and select Manage.

  [image]
- In the console tree, click Disk Management.

  [image]
- When you resize a partition, you choose to either expand or shrink the volume size. Please note that when shrinking the volume size, you must have enough empty space on the current partition. If you want to expand a volume size, make sure the hard drive has enough unallocated space available. To expand the size of the partition, right-click on the partition and select ‘Extend Volume…’.

  [image]
- Follow the ‘Extend Volume Wizard’, and type in the amount of space you would like to increase the volume by ‘Select the amount of space in MB:’.  Click the ‘Next’ button.

  [image]
- If you wish to shrink a partition, right-click on the partition and select ‘Shrink Volume…’.

  [image]
- The Disk Manager will then calculate if there is enough space to shrink the volume. If you have enough space, a dialog box will appear where you will be able to see the shrink space available. Enter the amount of space to shrink and hit the Shrink button.

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to delete partitions before extending, because those partitions are taking up space in your hard disc.
The error you're getting about dynamic discs is saying that your partitioning program does not support dynamic discs. You should use Windows Disc Manager to delete those partitions and then to create a new one.